# "Thread was being aborted." while redirecting to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am getting this error

```
Thread was being aborted.
```

When I am redirecting to a page.

The code to redirect is this.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Remove("userName");
    Label1.Text = "Looooo";
    Response.Redirect("MasterPage.master");
}
```

And the LinkButton1 is

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I wonder why are you redirecting to masterpage ? can you redirect to some other page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the other overload of [HttpResponse.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the `endResponse` parameter to `false`.

Change this

```
Response.Redirect("MasterPage.master");
```

to this

```
Response.Redirect("MasterPage.master", false);
```